# Gulp livereload issue (save twice)

Tags: sass, gulp, watch, livereload

I've recently switched from grunt to gulp, and so far have successfully configured gulp to do what I want. The only problem I'm having is with livereload, I'm finding that I have to save twice in order to see the compiled sass in the browser. Sass seems delayed

Is there a way I can ensure that livereload doesn't execute until sass is compiled? Here's my config:

```
// Dependencies
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var watch       = require('watch');
var livereload  = require('gulp-livereload');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); 
var cssmin      = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename      = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber     = require('gulp-plumber');
var notify      = require('gulp-notify');

onError = function(error){  
    notify.onError({
        title:    "Gulp",
        subtitle: "Failure!",
        message:  "<%= error.message %>",
        sound:    "Beep"
    })(error);

    this.emit('end');
};

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/css/**/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['concat']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch('*').on('change', livereload.changed);
});

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('src/css/style.scss')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded'}))
        .pipe(prefix('last 4 versions', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/build'))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

// Concat
gulp.task('concat', function(){
    gulp.src(['src/js/models/*.js', 'src/js/views/*.js', 'src/js/controllers/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/build'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
})

// Default
gulp.task('default', ['watch'], function(){
        livereload.listen();
});
```

Comment: Not directly an answer but remember to return stream from your `sass` & `concat` tasks -> `return gulp.src(..`

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `watch` task is telling gulp to run livereload **as soon as** one of your sass files changes, instead of waiting for the sass task to complete.

According to the [gulp-livereload documentation](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#sample-usages):

1. Add `.pipe(livereload())` as the last step in your `sass` task
2. Remove the `livereload.change` step from your sass file `watch` task.

That will ensure the livereload step will always happen last in your sass task, after your css has been compiled.